# Calling API and adding buttons programmatically

Tags: android

Long story short, I'm making an API call that retrieves a list of names.

For each name retrieved, I'd like to add a RelativeLayout (with some children) to a parent LinearLayout. The relative layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="11.79"
        android:background="#58585a"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to change the 'Small Text' and 'Large Text' fields to some data I received from querying the server.

What is the best way to go about achieving this? Can I store the above layout in a separate XML file, and quickly change the text values, and just drop it into the existing Linear Layout?

Comment: This looks like a textbook case for a `ListView`. Have you considered using one instead?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't quite fit my use case for a few reasons. In this case, I have a ScrollView that contains a LinearLayout, in which I'd like to insert the above code for each item pulled from my DB.

Comment: That still sounds like a textbook case for a `ListView`... :) Well, technically the approach you describe would work, but it looks so much like what `ListView` already does (and probably more efficiently, e.g. not creating all children views, reusing them, &c).

Comment: Well, you've sold me :) Feel free to add an answer to claim your sweet, sweet checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LISTING 1:**

**XML for the layout of each list item** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/
    apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#ffcccccc" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listImage"
    android:text="A List item title"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listImage"
    android:text="The List item description"
    android:textSize="14sp" />     
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Listing 2:**

**XML for layout containing the Listview** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ListView
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:fadingEdge="vertical"
          android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
          android:longClickable="true"
          android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       </ListView>
<!-- -->                                                        
       <TextView
          android:id="@android:id/empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="Loading feed data..." />
<!-- -->                                                        
</LinearLayout>
#1 Listview with id of "list"
#2 TextView with id of "empty"
```

**Listing 3:**

**ListActivity for the Dynamic ListView** -

```
public class DynamicListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.list);                             

          ImageListAdapter adapter = new ImageListAdapter(this);
          setListAdapter(adapter);                                   

          LoadFeedData loadFeedData = new LoadFeedData(adapter);
          loadFeedData.execute();                                    
       }
}
```

**Listing 4:**

**LoadFeedData class used for Loading the feed data** -

```
public class LoadFeedData extends
          AsyncTask<void, void,="" arraylist<entry="">> {       

       private final String mUrl =                               
         "URL_QUERING_TO_SERVER";

       private final ImageListAdapter mAdapter;

       public LoadFeedData(ImageListAdapter adapter) {          
          mAdapter = adapter;
       }

       private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {
          DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet httpGet = null;
          httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

          HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
          try {
             httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
             HttpEntity getResponseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
             return getResponseEntity.getContent();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             httpGet.abort();
          }
          return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected ArrayList<Entry> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          InputStream source = retrieveStream(mUrl);                   
          Reader reader = null;
          try {
             reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             return null;
          }
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          SearchResult result = gson.fromJson(reader,SearchResult.class);     
          return result.getFeed().getEntry();
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Entry> entries) {
          mAdapter.upDateEntries(entries);                       
       }
}
```

**Listing 5:**

**ImageListAdapter used to populate ListView with data and images** -

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

       private Context mContext;

       private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;                              

       private ArrayList<Entry> mEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();          

       private final ImageDownloader mImageDownloader;                      

       public ImageListAdapter(Context context) {                           
          mContext = context;
          mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          mImageDownloader = new ImageDownloader(context);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
          return mEntries.size();
       }

       @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {
          return mEntries.get(position);
       }

       @Override
       public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView,
             ViewGroup parent) {                                           
          RelativeLayout itemView;
          if (convertView == null) {                                        
             itemView = (RelativeLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                      R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

          } else {
             itemView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
          }

          ImageView imageView = (ImageView)
             itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);                        
          TextView titleText = (TextView)
             itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);                        
          TextView descriptionText = (TextView)
             itemView.findViewById(R.id.listDescription);                  

          String imageUrl = mEntries.get(position).getContent().getSrc();   
          mImageDownloader.download(imageUrl, imageView);                   

          String title = mEntries.get(position).getTitle().get$t();
          titleText.setText(title);
          String description =
             mEntries.get(position).getSummary().get$t();
          if (description.trim().length() == 0) {
             description = "Sorry, no description for this image.";
          }
          descriptionText.setText(description);

          return itemView;
       }

       public void upDateEntries(ArrayList<Entry> entries) {
          mEntries = entries;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

Great! This way you will load dynamic data from server and display it in a listview.
Obviously, you may change some of it or more to add as suitable for your application.
Cheers!

Comment: I had to modify this somewhat but this got me on the right path! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By this approach if you received list that contains 10+ items your app will have very-very low performance. 99% probability that all your goals may be achieved by using ListView with your custom adapter. In this case android will create views only if it is showing on screen. In your case views will exists even if they not needed.

Although if you still want to use your approach, you can find TextView by this Id and changed their text.

Approximate code

```
...
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
customView = inflater.inflate(%Your_layout_id%, null);   // Put id of your xml layout file

largeTextView = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
largeTextView.setText(%your_large_text%);
TextView smallTextView = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
smallTextView.setText(%your_small_text%);
...
```